# WPF - Convert file to Byte[] to BitmapSource using JpegBitmapDecoder

Tags: wpf, image, bitmapsource, varbinarymax

I need to read a jpg file and latyer display it in an Image controll. 
The following works perfectly:

```
imgTwo.Source = FetchImage(@"C:\Image075.jpg");

public BitmapSource FetchImage(string URLlink)
{
      JpegBitmapDecoder decoder = null;
      BitmapSource bitmapSource = null;
      decoder = new JpegBitmapDecoder(new Uri(URLlink, UriKind.Absolute), BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
      bitmapSource = decoder.Frames[0];
      bitmapSource.Freeze();
      return bitmapSource;
}
```

My problem is that I need to keep this image in a database as Byte[] (varbinary(MAX) and read it from there, not directly from a file as the above does. 
So I need to either have a Byte[] as input to this function instead of a URLlink string, or save the BitmapSource as Byte[]. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JpegBitmapDecoder` has a [second constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602494.aspx) that accepts a `Stream`. Just pass in a `MemoryStream` containing your `byte[]`:

```
using(var stream = new MemoryStream(yourByteArray))
{
    decoder = new JpegBitmapDecoder(stream,
                                    BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat,
                                    BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
}
```